# np.where condition is not getting satisfied

Tags: pandas, numpy

In the following line of code, I get the error shown below.

```
d3["WOE"] = np.where(((d3.DIST_EVENT==0) | (d3.DIST_NON_EVENT ==0)) ,np.nan ,np.log(d3.DIST_EVENT/d3.DIST_NON_EVENT))
```

I if the numerator or denominator is 0, then the condition for np.nan should satisfy and d3["WOE"] shoud be nan. Why is the following error being produced?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FloatingPointError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-a9b015683238> in <module>
----> 1 final_iv, IV = data_vars(df_leads_short,df_leads_short.close_flag)
      2 IV.sort_values('IV')

<ipython-input-55-5530ad13fa5a> in data_vars(df1, target)
    122                 count = count + 1
    123             else:
--> 124                 conv = char_bin(target, df1[i])
    125                 conv["VAR_NAME"] = i
    126                 count = count + 1

<ipython-input-55-5530ad13fa5a> in char_bin(Y, X)
     92     d3["DIST_EVENT"] = d3.EVENT/d3.sum().EVENT
     93     d3["DIST_NON_EVENT"] = d3.NONEVENT/d3.sum().NONEVENT
---> 94     d3["WOE"] = np.where(((d3.DIST_EVENT==0) | (d3.DIST_NON_EVENT ==0)) ,np.nan ,np.log(d3.DIST_EVENT/d3.DIST_NON_EVENT))
     95     #d3["WOE"] = np.log(d3.DIST_EVENT/d3.DIST_NON_EVENT)
     96     d3["IV"] = np.where((d3.DIST_EVENT==0) | (d3.DIST_NON_EVENT ==0 ),np.nan ,(d3.DIST_EVENT-d3.DIST_NON_EVENT)*np.log(d3.DIST_EVENT/d3.DIST_NON_EVENT))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __array_ufunc__(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs)
   1934         self, ufunc: Callable, method: str, *inputs: Any, **kwargs: Any
   1935     ):
-> 1936         return arraylike.array_ufunc(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs)
   1937 
   1938     # ideally we would define this to avoid the getattr checks, but

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/arraylike.py in array_ufunc(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs)
    356         # ufunc(series, ...)
    357         inputs = tuple(extract_array(x, extract_numpy=True) for x in inputs)
--> 358         result = getattr(ufunc, method)(*inputs, **kwargs)
    359     else:
    360         # ufunc(dataframe)

FloatingPointError: divide by zero encountered in log
```

Comment: `where` is a python function.  Its argments are evaluated in full before being passed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do

```
cond = ((d3.DIST_EVENT==0) | (d3.DIST_NON_EVENT ==0))
d3.loc[~cond,"WOE"] = np.log(d3.loc[~cond,"DIST_EVENT"]/d3.loc[~cond,"DIST_NON_EVENT"]))
```

Since the np.where still need calculated the `np.log(d3.DIST_EVENT/d3.DIST_NON_EVENT)` which will still yield the same error.`np.where` is just selection.

Comment: I see. I did not realize that. Your solution works perfectly. Thank you